# Excel Display % markup in Cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My boss has made a very anal request that spreadsheet that currently calculate markups from cost prices be formatted differently.

Currently I have added the formula as follows;

```
Cost = X
Markup = 110% 
Sale = Cost * Markup
```

However, they don't like the fact that the Markup cell is displaying as 110% as it is implying that there is a 110% markup.

Is there a way of formatting this cell so that it just shows 10% as a display value?

Comment: Is it possible to change the formula of `Sale` to `Cost * (1 + Markup)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is just put in the correct 10%
the correct formula is:

```
 Sale=Cost + Cost*Markup
```

where the markup is 10% or better 0,1
If you simplify it you get

```
 Sale=Cost*(1+Markup)
```

This makes it much clearer and easier to enter the number

Hope it helps!

Comment: It should do. Plus one.

Answer (score 1):

Now is the chance for your personal effectiveness skills to flourish.

Formats that display different numbers to the real numbers are *really* pernicious (they completely obfuscate formulas in any cells dependent on such cells), and Excel makes such things intentionally very difficult to accomplish. At the time of writing I believe, thankfully, that your request is impossible.

What you should do is to use a simple formula `boss_value = real_value - 1`, and format that new column as a normal percentage. Hide the intermediate data if you must.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. I thought as much (sorry I'm not as experienced with excel as I'd like to be :) ). Just to clarify, your saying the layout would basically be

CostCell = X
MarkupValue = 10%
SalePrice = X * (Markup + 1)

Comment: I wouldn't make it that complicated. Just subtract 1 from the current cell in a new formula.